# Completly remove windows from my computer

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted

I had dual boot on my pc (windows 8 and ubuntu 13.10). I recently removed windows partitions and ended with the following partitions:

[image]

I seem unable to use my unllocated space (Gparted doesn't let me expand the remaning partitions to take advantage of it).

Unfortunately the pc still shows me the boot menu to choose the operating system to boot. How can I can I fix this since I only have one OS?

Also can I remove the fat32 partition and unknown partition? Can I use my unallocated space?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Delete all partitions [except Ubuntu partition] and 

create a new ext4 or ntfs partition(s) from that unallocated space.

[**Deleting partition causes lose of data from that partition**]

Comment: Is it safe to delete fat32 and unknown partition?

Comment: do not remove fat32 it is mounted at /boot/efi and it is Ubuntu efi folder. removing it will fail booting of ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about removing the unallocated partitions, but they don't seem to be taking a lot of space anyway. But if you removed the ones having Windows installed, you just need to update your boot manager so it detects that there's not Windows anymore.

Open a terminal and execute this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should probe the partitions for installed O.S. and detect your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: The problem is that it finds a windows partition. I think its the sda2 (fat32) partition that it thinks is windows partition. So I'm guessing if I remove that partition I will be ok.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that safely. According gparted, that's the partition where boot is installed, you may break your grub configuration if you erase that partition.

Comment: Ok. In that case is any other way to remove grub menu on boot and windows boot files?

Comment: The only thing I cant think of is formatting the partition /dev/sda2 and, without rebooting, reinstall grub with "sudo grub install /dev/sda". Then, re run the sudo update-grub if the installation is reported correctly. But as I said, yours is a weird partition table so I would advice you to backup your files before you try.

Comment: I will give it a try and will post the result here. Thanks.